# Unable to convert JSON object to Java Object correctly

Tags: java, json, mongodb, rest, gson

I am facing an issue while converting an JSON to a Java Object.

My Json is as below

```
{
   "_id":{
      "$oid":"5981428cf1aa82a313540b76"
   },
   "productId":1,
   "name":"The Big Lebowski",
   "currency":{
       "currency":"USD",
       "value":40.5
   }
}
```

I am retrieving json as DBObject for Product from the MongoDB database.

```
DBObject dbObject = productsCollection.findOne(searchQuery);
if(dbObject != null)
{
    Product product = (Product) AppUtils.fromDBObject(dbObject, Product.class);
    return Optional.of(product);
}
```

Product is return as

> Product[productId = 1, productName= null, currencyPrice = null]

My fromDBObject method in AppUtils.java is as below :

```
public static Object fromDBObject(DBObject dbObj, Class<?> clazz) 
{
    String json = dbObj.toString();
    return new Gson().fromJson(json, clazz);
}
```

My POJO is as below :

```
public class Product 
{
   private long productId;
   private String productName;
   private CurrencyPrice currencyPrice;
   // getter and setter 
}

public class CurrencyPrice
{
   private double value;
   private String currency;
   // getter and setter
}
```

I am unable to understand where it is going wroing for the DBObject object with json to translate to Product object.

Thanks !

Comment: Well there actually is a [`.toJson()`](http://api.mongodb.com/java/current/com/mongodb/BasicDBObject.html#toJson--) method on `BasicDBObject` which is of course different to `.toString(). But really you should just be using the `BasicDBObject` directly, since it has the same interface as a [`AbstractMap`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/AbstractMap.html?is-external=true). No need to coerce to JSON and then back to an object form. It's already a usable interface, and **not** JSON.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try changing your POJO property names to match

```
public class Product 
{
   private long productId;
   private String name;
   private CurrencyPrice currency;
   // getter and setter 
}
```

Comment: Thanks yes , I wasn't adhering to the correct variable name